# Matching Kinect's skeleton data to a specific part of .fbx model

Tags: xna, kinect

I am developing a game in which i am using a character model. Using Kinect i am now able to apply all the motions to the model as per player in front of Kinect camera.
Now i want to apply only hand motions to the model and remaining body has to be fixed as it is.
         Can any one help me to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want a fixed Skeleton that you will updated the joint info based on the Skeleton input and use this to update your UI - as opposed to drawing the input skeleton to the UI.

There is an issue with creating your own Skeleton objects as the Microsoft Kinect SDK developers made the JointType of the Joint class internal -  this means that the JointType can not be updated and therefore the joint positions cannot be updated.

So to get around this you need:

1. Have the joint positions saved in your code that describe a stationary user
2. Create a new Skeleton object
3. Copy the incoming Skeleton object from the sensor to your newly instantiated Skeleton.
4. Now update this Skeleton with the stationary points except for the joints that you require the positions from the sensor

The key point here is step 3.  This allows you to create your own Skeleton objects with your custom position data, which is what you will need to do to solve your problem.